# Select Option tag doesn't show it's own value in vue after deploying on AWS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, deployment

I'm making up a signup form on vue3 with element plus.
And there is an issue that the option tags don't show their labels or values after deploying. Before deploying, it looked okay but now it has disappeared and doesn't pass any values to the form either. Also, it doesn't change if I click any options which are now blank.
I want it to appear back.

There was no error message on the console.

Here's the partial code of the form.

```
<!-- partial code from the form in the template tag-->
<el-form-item prop="grade" label="Grade/Class/Num" :label-width="state.formLabelWidth">
  <el-select v-model="state.form.grade" placeholder="Grade" style="width: 35%">
    <el-option label="1st" value="1"></el-option>
    <el-option label="2nd" value="2"></el-option>
    <el-option label="3rd" value="3"></el-option>
    <el-option label="4th" value="4"></el-option>
    <el-option label="5th" value="5"></el-option>
    <el-option label="6th" value="6"></el-option>
  </el-select>
    <el-select v-model="state.form.class_no" placeholder="Class" style="width: 30%">
    <el-option label="1st" value="01"></el-option>
    <el-option label="2nd" value="02"></el-option>
    <el-option label="3rd" value="03"></el-option>
    <el-option label="4th" value="04"></el-option>
    <el-option label="5th" value="05"></el-option>
    <el-option label="6th" value="06"></el-option>
  </el-select>
  <el-input v-model="state.form.snum" placeholder="Num" style="width: 35%"></el-input>
</el-form-item>
```

Here's the partial code in which I defined form values in the script tag.

```
const state = reactive({
  form: {
    id: '',
    password: '',
    passwordConfirmation: '',
    name: '',
    grade: '',
    class_no: '',
    snum: '',
    sex: '',
    phone: '',
    parents_phone:'',
    address: '',
    password_question: '',
    password_answer: '',
  },

  return { state }
})
```

I've heard if the v-model value is undefined, the option value could disappear so I checked and found out it isn't undefined but "

And here's what I found on the developer tool's Element section. It doesn't have any innnerTexts in the span tag

```
<!-- Before deploying -->
<li class="el-select-dropdown__item">
  <span>1st</span>
</li>
<li class="el-select-dropdown__item">
  <span>2nd</span>
</li>
<li class="el-select-dropdown__item">
  <span>3rd</span>
</li>
<li class="el-select-dropdown__item">
  <span>4th</span>
</li>
<li class="el-select-dropdown__item">
  <span>5th</span>
</li>
<li class="el-select-dropdown__item">
  <span>6th</span>
</li>
```

```
<!-- After deploying -->
<li class="el-select-dropdown__item">
  <span></span>
</li>
<li class="el-select-dropdown__item">
  <span></span>
</li>
<li class="el-select-dropdown__item">
  <span></span>
</li>
<li class="el-select-dropdown__item">
  <span></span>
</li>
<li class="el-select-dropdown__item">
  <span></span>
</li>
<li class="el-select-dropdown__item">
  <span></span>
</li>
```

Here are the pictures for being clearer

[The picture that I intended](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzJFX.png)

[The picture I got after the depolyment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swEkT.png)

Comment: what are these `<el-*` elements - are you using some sort of framework? Also, are you using something to compile/bundle your code for deployment?

Comment: <el-elements> tags are form element plus which is an [UI library](https://element-plus.org/#/en-US)
If you're asking about something like nginx, yes I do

Comment: no, I'm asking about webpack or the like, that "compiles" the code for deployment

Comment: how are you including "Element Plus" in your project - exactly

Comment: Hmm I still don't understand first comment with lack of knowledge, I downloaded Element plus with npm.

Comment: ahh, so you are *bundling* some how

Comment: Please help me. Is there anything you might need to know?